# Help understanding some C# code

Tags: c#

Can someone please explain to me the following method? I don't quite understand what it does, and how it does it.

```
private List<Label> CreateLabels(params string[] names)
{
    return new List<Label>(names.Select(x => new Label { ID = 0, Name = x }));
}
```

Comment: What do you think it means? Where are you having a problem. Why do you want someone to do your work for you?

Comment: @John Saunders - LOL. This is a Q&A site.

Comment: I see no question marks.

Comment: @Daniel: what is his question? This is a Q&A site, not an "explain to me things I cannot understand" site.

Comment: Huh? You're saying people should be banned from asking questions about things they don't already understand? Sigh.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Let's separate it into different bits:

```
private List<Label> CreateLabels(params string[] names)
```

This means we're declaring a method returning a list of `Label` references. We're taking an array of string references as a parameters, and it's declared as a *parameter array* which means callers can just specify the arguments like this:

```
List<Label> labels = CreateLabels("first", "second", "third");
```

(Or they can explicitly pass in an array of strings as normal.)

Now to understand the body, we'll split it up like this:

```
IEnumerable<Labael> labels = names.Select(x => new Label { ID = 0, Name = x });
List<Label> list = new List<Label>(labels);
return list;
```

The second and third lines should be fairly simple - it's just constructing a `List<Label>` from a sequence of labels, and then returning it. The first line is likely to be the one causing problems.

`Select` is an *extension method* on the generic `IEnumerable<T>` type (a sequence of elements of type `T`) which lazily returns a new sequence by executing a *projection* in the form of a delegate.

In this case, the delegate is specified with a *lambda* expression like this:

```
x => new Label { ID = 0, Name = x }
```

That says, "Given `x`, create a `Label` and set its ID property to 0, and its `Name` property to `x`." Here the type of `x` is inferred to be `string` because we're calling `Select` on a string array. This isn't just using a lambda expression, but also an *object initializer expression*. The `new Label { ID = 0, Name = x }` part is equivalent to:

```
Label tmp = new Label();
tmp.ID = 0;
tmp.Name = x;
Label result = tmp;
```

We *could* have written a separate method to do this:

```
private static Label CreateLabel(string x)
{
    Label tmp = new Label();
    tmp.ID = 0;
    tmp.Name = x;
    return tmp;
}
```

and then called:

```
IEnumerable<Label> labels = names.Select(CreateLabel);
```

That's effectively what the compiler's doing for you behind the scenes.

So the projection creates a sequence of labels with the names given by the parameter. The code then creates a list of labels from that sequence, and returns it.

Note that it would (IMO) be more idiomatic LINQ to have written:

```
return names.Select(x => new Label { ID = 0, Name = x }).ToList();
```

rather than *explicitly* creating the `List<Label>`.

Answer (score 9):

In general, the meaning behind well written code can often be deduced by the code itself. This is called "self-documenting code." Code that doesn't follow this, should hopefully be accompanied by comments.

In this case, here is how you could figure out what the code does:

The method gives you some key bits of information:

- The name of the method. This lets you know what the method does. In this example, the method is called `CreateLabels`
- The method's signature. This indicates what the method requires. In this example, there is an array of type string, with the keyword `params`. The keyword `params` indicates that this method will accept one or more names as inputs to the method, and will collect them into a single array.
- The method's return type. This will tell you want the method will give you when it's finished. In this example, it returns a List of Labels.

So, since the method is called `CreateLabels`, takes an series of string called names, and returns a list of lables, we might say that **"Given several names, this method will return a list of lables"**

Now if you need to know how the method is doing this, then have a look at the body.

`return new List<Label>(names.Select(x => new Label { ID = 0, Name = x }));`

For someone who does not understand linq or lambda expressions, this is a bit difficult to understand.

Lets work our way from outside to inside:

`return new List<Label>()` constructs a new list and returns the new list, and causes the method to exit.

`names.Select()` Is a method that will apply a set of operations to all the objects in the array, and return a new collection which will contain the result of applying those operations.

`x=>new Label {ID = 0, Name = x}` is a lambda expression that says: x goes to a new Label object who's ID field is 0, and Name is the value of `x`.

Putting it all together, the statement `return new List<Label>(names.Select(x => new Label { ID = 0, Name = x }));` is creating a new Label Object for each name in `names` and stores it into a new list, which is returned at the end of the method.

It is a way of also writing:

```
List<Labels> toReturn = new List<Labels>();
foreach(string name in names)
{
 Label l = new Label();
 l.ID = 0;
 l.Name = name;
 toReturn.Add(l);
}
return toReturn;
```

Answer (score 6):

This simply takes a variable sized set of names, and turns them into a list of labels with the ID set to 0.

```
List<Label> labels = CreateLabels("one", "two", "three");
foreach(Label label in labels)
{
    Console.WriteLine(label.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(label.ID);
}
```

This will print:

> one
> 0
> two
> 0
> three
> 0

Answer (score 3):

This code returns collection (`List`) of `Label` classes. Foreach string variable in input parameter `names` it creates new instance of class Label with ID property equal to 0 and Name property equal to current `names` element

You can change this code to following:

```
private List<Label> CreateLabels(params string[] names)
{
        List<Label> result = new List<Label>();
        foreach(string name in names)
        {
                Label label = new Label()
                label.ID = 0;
                label.Name = name;
                result.Add(label);
        }
        result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to learn this  [linq 101 sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx) then you know yourself the meaning of this code.

Comment: It has more confusing elements than LINQ. `params`, lambda expression, and the constructor property initializers (is that what they're called?). Quite a lot for one line of code `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here goes:

```
    new Label { ID = 0, Name = x }
```

This is creating a new instance of `Label` with `ID` set to 0 and `Name` set to `x`.

```
    x => new Label { ID = 0, Name = x }
```

This is called a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) - it is defining an anonymous function which accepts a single input (`x`) and returns a new instance of label.  You may find it easier to read `x => ...` as "`x` goes to ...".

```
    names.Select(x => new Label { ID = 0, Name = x })
```

This is calling the `Select` method on the `names` object, passing the above lambda expression as a parameter.  We can see that the type of `names` is a `string` array.  This is in fact an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) - `string[]` does not define a method `Select`, this the Select method ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357126.aspx) on MSDN) is defined elsewhere (in the `System.Core` assembly)

The select method simply "Projects each element of a sequence into a new form." - essentially it converts each element in the array into another object (in our case an instance of `Label`)

To clarify: The above statement returns an [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) (a kind of collection) of `Label` objects, one for each string in `names`.

```
    return new List<Label>(...);
```

This returns a new List of `Label` objects - in our case we are passing in our IEnumeable returned by the call to `Select`.

**In short:**

This method outputs a List of `Label` objects, one for each string in `names`.  Each `Label` object has its `ID` set to `0`, and its `Name` set to the string value from the `names` array.

Does this help explain what's going on here?